# Comments on the held questions are deleted

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments, on-hold

> **put on hold** questions can only be commented, voted, and edited!

I commented on a question, and later the question was **put on hold**. After refreshing the page the comments were also been deleted.

Is this an error or it happens that way only?

Comment: Definitely not a bug; comments can and often are deleted if they're not actually valuable.

Comment: Who does it? (Moderator or any reputation criteria)

Comment: Depends on the comment.  Certain comments *can* be instantly deleted by anyone at a certain rep threshold (and I can't recall it off the top of my head).  The lion's share of comments are deleted *en masse* by a moderator as the resolution to a mod flag about it.

Comment: @Makoto Insta nuke is not rep based as far as I know, only content based. So if you can flag (at 15 rep) you're good to go.

Comment: Can you share a link to the question? Or tell us if it was closed as duplicate? Because that also has a known side effect on comments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only sort of comment that is deleted *automatically* is the "possible duplicate of..." comment, which is posted automatically on behalf of a user voting to close a question as a duplicate. When the question gets closed as a duplicate by a consensus of voters, such comments are automatically deleted because they are clearly obsolete—you don't need a comment containing the link to the "master" question, because there's a big yellow box to display the link.

In all other cases, comments must be manually deleted. There are three ways for comments to be deleted:

1. Self-deletion by the user who originally posted them.
2. Manually by a diamond moderator.
3. Automatically (by the Community user, who is actually a diamond moderator) in response to a flag (this requires that the comment being flagged contain certain blacklisted content; otherwise, the flags are reviewed manually by moderators).

I'm 99% certain that the motivation for your asking this question was the deleted comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55779927/insert-table-dropdown-like-tinymce).

It was closed as "too broad" by the community. There were 5 votes to close as "too broad", and one flag recommending closure as "too broad"—a pretty strong consensus

The question was brought to my attention because of a flag on one of the comments. One of your comments was flagged as "unfriendly or unkind". I declined the flag, because I didn't think your comment qualified as "unfriendly or unkind", but when I reviewed all of the comments, I determined that they had all outlived their usefulness. Since the question was now closed, the problems with it are better explained by the description in the big yellow banner than they were by the comments.

For the purposes of transparency, here are all the deleted comments on that question:

[image: screenshot of all deleted comments; not worth taking the time to transcribe (you aren't missing anything valuable)]

The "I have done nothing"/"I need you to write it all for me" comment by the original asker confirmed that the "too broad" closure of the question was appropriate. Leaving it in place wasn't going to do anything but attract more downvotes.

The "I told you so!" comment that you left (the last one) was particularly unhelpful. I think the asker got the idea.

Comment: The comment which was flagged was that really hurt the OP or the reader? Was that unkind?

Comment: I intentionally did not mention *who* flagged the comment, since flags are anonymous. But yes, apparently someone did think your comment was "unfriendly or unkind". I didn't agree, which is why i declined the flag. It could be argued that the statement, "This family is not a magician..." is unnecessarily snarky. But the only thing I found particularly hurtful about it was the poor grammar, which it pained me to read.

Comment: There's a 4th case, if the flag is the Nth abusive flag, rather than a single flag on the blacklist. (I forget what N is.)